# I am using React Router and the path params which I was passing has a "/", the react router taking that as seperate path and It was not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<Route exact path="/name/:username" component={Home}/>
```

while using that in other component, to redirect to this path, it is not redirecting because I was having "/" in the username(i.e., in the route param)

```
  const username = "/john/bradley"
  <Link to='name/username'>Click Here </Link>
```

Comment: `<Route exact path="/name/:firstname/:lastname" component={Home}/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to conditionally match a route path that is either (1) a single "username" path segment or (2) a "firstname" segment then a "lastname" segment you'll need to declare path matchers for both.

Example:

```
<Route
  exact
  path={["/name/:firstname/:lastname", "/name/:username"]}
  component={Home}
/>
```

Then form the link targets correctly.

Link to a `"/name/john/bradly"` (`"/name/:firstname/:lastname"`):

```
const username = "/john/bradley";
```

Link to a `"/name/johnBradly"` (`"/name/:username"`):

```
const username = "/johnBradley";

...

<Link to={`name/${username}`}>Click Here </Link>
```

For something like a username field I'd suggest passing this as a queryString parameter so you void the need for odd route path matchers.

Example:

```
<Route exact path="/name" component={Home}/>
```

...

```
const username = "john bradley";

...

<Link
  to={{
    pathname: 'name',
    search: `?username=${username}`,
  }}
>
  Click Here
</Link>
```

Then in the `Home` component access the username from the `location.search` object string.

```
const { search } = useLocation();
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
const username = searchParams.get("username"); // "john bradley"
```

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, Thanks for adding the answer but my question is I am having "/" in the username value and that is being taken as a name/john/bradley by the router and it is not navigating to Home Component.

Comment: @SrinuRachakonda You need a route that can match `"/name/john/bradley"`, declaring a `path` prop with a pattern `"/name/:firstname/:lastname"` makes this possible. The `Home` component will then need to check for the `username` path param and if it's undefined make the assumption there are the `firstname` and `lastname` params to use since one or the other will necessarily exist based on the route path being matched. Does this make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would take it as another route.

If you insist on pushing your name with a "/" might be best to replace it with a "-" instead.

i.e

```
const username = "/john-bradley"
```

Comment: No, actually the username is coming as an api response and I need that in the route path. so isn't there any other way